# Generic parameters in a generate

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am unable to get around the "Unable to bind parameter" error in Verilog.

I have a 2D array `weights` containing some values that are read into it using `$readmemh`. I want to then instantiate a known number of instances of module called `pe`, and each instance must take a value at index `i` in the array and set its generic parameter `weight` to `weights[i]`.

Here is the code and the error I am getting.  What am I doing wrong?

```
reg [data_size-1:0] weights [0:(array_size * array_size) - 1];

genvar i;
generate
    // Read the weights
    $readmemh(array_weights,weights);
    for (i = 0; i < array_size*array_size; i = i + 1) begin : pe_cells
        pe #(.weight(weights[i]), .data_size(data_size)) pe_cells_i (
            .clk(clk)
        );
    end
endgenerate
```

```
error: Unable to bind parameter `weights[i]' in `array.pe_cells[0]'
```

Comment: The post may be a duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342762/systemverilog-how-to-give-different-parameters-to-modules-in-the-same-array

Answer (score 0):

`weights` is declared as a `reg`, which means it is a variable, but you must not pass a variable value to a module instance parameter (`weight`).  You can only connect a constant type to a parameter.  You can use a `parameter` array, but you can not assign to that array using `$readmemh`.

Answer (score 0):

`Parameters` to a module must be known at compile time.

Values produced by reading a memory are not known at compile time.

From IEEE 1364-2005 section 4.10.1

> Parameters represent constants; hence, it is illegal to modify their value at run time.

Here are a couple possible solutions:

Solution 1) Use a SystemVerilog assignment pattern like this.
`// 4 element array of integers.`
`integer my_array_of_integers_with_values [1:0] = '{0:5, 1:1, 2:3, 3:128 };`

The values of my_array_of_integers_with_values is known at compile time.

Solution 2) Use a script (python, perl, bash, tcl, matlab, etc.) that reads values from the file (same file $readmemh() uses), then writes out a an assignment pattern with the needed values into a SystemVerilog package. Next, import the package into the module which needs the parameters.  The script runs as part of the build, prior to compilation.  This would be easier to maintain if the file changes frequently during the design process.

I would use choose between solution 1 and solution 2 based on the number of parameters.  If the number were small use 1, for a large number choose 2.  Its up to you to decide what is large or small or how much burden it is to manage the numbers manually each time the file changes.

Comment: Yes, I do know that, so what could be a work around?

Comment: I actually thought that using a script was a “dirty” way, but if it seems okay I guess will do so, thanks